# VBA Dictionary if exists?

Tags: arrays, vba, dictionary

I have an array called flArr and i am transferring it to a dictionary and testing elements from an another array if exists then i am adding it to a list box but i don't know, somehow it is not working giving me "object required" error. Any idea?.

```
Set dic_cc = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
dic_cc = flArr 'transferring array to dictionary 

    For Each f In heArr 'another array heArr        
        If dic_cc.Exists(f) Then Me.FilterList.AddItem f    
    Next
```

Thanks

Comment: You cannot assign an array to a dictionary like that - you will need to loop over the array and add the items one by one.

Comment: yes i can. I can loop thorugh dic_cc and i see all elements of that array. i have only problem in this line If dic_cc.Exists(f) Then Me.FilterList.AddItem f

Comment: No you can't.  Try declaring dic_cc `As Object` and see what happens.  What you're doing in your current code is assigning the variable `dic_cc` to the array `flArr` - at that point it ceases to be a Dictionary object and becomes an array. That only works if you declare dic_cc as Variant (or at least not as `Object`).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think an array in VBA is enumerable. You need loop though each element in the array and check against the dictionary like so:

```
dim i as long

For i= 0 to to ubound(myArray)
 If dic_cc.Exists(myArray[i]) then
  me.FilterList.AddItem myArray[i]
 endif

next i
```

Comment: Declare ```Dim ar(1 To 3) As Integer``` and then add some items to it. Then ```For Each it In ar``` is valid and can be used.